# Does django take SCRIPT_NAME into account when using the default LOGIN_URL

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.0.2 and trying to figure out how to get the @login_required working correctly.

When I use the built-in server it redirects to the default login_url, or my LOGIN_URL as defined in settings.py as expected.

What is not clear to me is how to deploy to the server where my site is not at the root. In my templates I use the url template tag, and in the views I can access request.META['SCRIPT_NAME'], but for some reason it doesn't seem to apply to the LOGIN_URL used.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting called `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME` that you should use to set the location of your script, if it's not hosted at the root directory. You can add it to the login/logout URLs:

```
# This is needed because we're running the app in non-root directory of web server
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/myapp.cgi/'

LOGIN_URL = FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME + 'accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME + 'accounts/logout/'
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#force-script-name